# How to use "undertaken" as an adjective

Tags: adjectives

> The analysis of undertaken research.

Is this statement correct? I mean is "undertaken" the correct adjective?

Comment: "undertaken" is the past participle of "to undertake". It can be placed after the noun: "The analysis of (the) research undertaken".

Comment: How can we know whether this is the correct word to use without knowing what you want your sentence to mean?

Comment: I'm sorry I can't explain this clearly but I'm still learning English. It's a title which describes the diagram and should mean the analysis of research which have been conducted.

Comment: Can you identify the content of the diagram, at least in general terms? Is it a labeled pie chart or something else? From the minimal description you've provided so far, I'm skeptical about the need for "The analysis of" in your diagram title.

Answer (score 1):

The word 'undertaken' is fine, but I believe the sentence structure should be 'The analysis of research undertaken...'.